# My coolant has oil in it could this be the coil?

Tags: coolant, cooling-system, oil-leak

I have oil in my coolant. I don't have coolant in the oil. I got told it will want flushing out and a new coil. I have a Vauxhall Astra 2006 1.6 engine

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that by coil they meant the oil cooler. These seem to be a weak point in these cars (based on [this thread](http://www.astraownersclub.com/vb/showthread.php/649943-How-many-have-bypassed-OIL-COOLER-1-7DTI-(y17dt)) on the Astra Owners' Club site). Some of the folks there are suggesting bypassing the oil cooler claiming that it is only needed when towing.